# Dynamically select option with jQuery 2.0

Tags: jquery

The following jsfillde is working with jQuery 1.8.3, but not with any newer version.. and I cannot find a way to resolve it.

http://jsfiddle.net/hyBXd/

```
$("[name=ids] option").each(function() {
  if( $(this).attr('value') == 2 ) { $(this).attr('selected','selected'); }
});
```

Could anyone help me with this?!
Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hyBXd/1/ changed the library to jQuery 2.0 and works fine here... ?

Comment: Your fiddle actually works fine for me. I am using the latest Chrome

Comment: @ChrisDixon thats the thing! it does not work for me..

Comment: @musefan Im using the latest Safari, I dont know about Chrome.. It could be a browser specific glitch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr()`:

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as
>   the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the
>   .prop() method

```
$(function() {
    $("[name=ids] option").each(function() {
        if( $(this).prop('value') == 2 ) { $(this).prop('selected','selected'); }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of why this isn't working, you can heavily simplify your script to work with the latest 1.x jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("[name=ids]").val(2);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hyBXd/2/

Comment: Thanks for this! I will stick to this one, however, I think Eli pointed out the problem I was struggling with.. Thats why I chose that answer, but thank you.. it is really a lot shorter..! :)